# implement a hash map that takes in k = Date object v = an array

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Hello I would like to implement a Hash map that maps a specific Date to an array of ints. the size of the array is 32

I tried this and it compiles :

`HashMap<Date,int[]> coord_map = new HashMap<Date, int[]>();`

but I am not sure how this works since I did not give a size for the array of integers.

also I tired this:

```
int[] arr = new int[32];
for(int i =0; i <32; i++){
arr[i] = 0; // initialize the array to 0. 
}
HashMap<Date, arr> attraction_date = new HashMap<Date, arr>();
```

this gives me a compiler error "Cannot find a class or type named arr"

thank you

**I now have a followup question:**

I am successfully using one hash map that takes in a date and maps it to an int array. 
now I want to use multiple instances of this hashmap. since my project deals with theme park data, there will be one hashmap for every attraction.
so how would I implement an array list of hash maps. To keep track of 20 attractions?
If anyone can show me a sample setup code, that initializes everything, that would be helpful.

thank you again,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have on top is good, you don't need to specify a size.
This will work

```
Map<Date, int[]> coordMap = new HashMap<Date, int[]>();
coordMap.put(aDate, new int[]{1,2});
coordMap.put(anotherDate, new int[]{3,4,5,6});
...
```

So each value `int[]` can have a different size.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you do. If the problem requires that you have an array of **exactly 32** ints then create a wrapper class IntArray32 and use `HashMap<Date, IntArray32>`. Otherwise what you have written will work, it will simply allow you to have int array of any size as value.