# implementing an Array list of hashmaps

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

this is more of a **follow up question** to 
[implement a hash map that takes in k = Date object v = an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455311/implement-a-hash-map-that-takes-in-k-date-object-v-an-array)
I am writing my code in Java 
I am successfully using one hash map that takes in a date and maps it to an int array. now I want to use multiple instances of this hashmap. since my project deals with theme park data, there will be one hashmap for every attraction.
so how would I implement an array list of hash maps. To keep track of 20 attractions? If anyone can show me a sample setup code, that initializes everything, that would be helpful.

thanks,

Comment: I would create a class for the attractions, and hold those in a set.

Comment: +1 for @jlordo. Don't just use data structres. Define classes. Use objects with encapsulated behavior and data.

Comment: Don't forget that Java is an Object Orientated Programming language and you should learn to create your own classes.  This makes the implementation easier in the long run.

Comment: (Implementing nominative classes also has the "side effect" of making code self-documenting - much unlike `m.get(x)[y].get(z)`.)

Comment: ok this makes sense. I will create a class that encapsulates a hash map. thank you